# Do tasks scheduled with ScheduledExecutorService run if the app is not in the foreground?

Tags: android

If I schedule a task to run in the future with ScheduledExecutorService, and my app is in the background at the scheduled time, will it still run?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this and the answer is YES.

Comment: What if the app is closed?

Comment: @RamjiSeetharaman I believe that the ScheduledExecutorService will not be invoked if the app is closed - the code runs within the app's onCreate, and if the app is not in memory, it will not be invoked.

You should try invoking it in a Service of some kind.